# how to redirect to a page while submitting a form

Tags: jquery, forms, redirect

I'm wondering how to redirect to a thank you page (or div) after you click the submit button from a form within a div using jQuery?

Comment: Do the redirect from your server where the data was submitted to. Exactly how you do that will depend on what language that's written in, but you should be able to Google it very easily.

Comment: Please consider adding the code of what you have tried. I encourage you to have a look on [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide.

Comment: "submit a form using jquery" is a bit vague - are you submitting the form or generating an ajax POST?  If submit, then redirect from the server as your current page will no longer exist.  If ajax, then a simple `location.href='newpage'` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Use this-

```
$(location).attr('href','http://example.com/example');
```

And tie it to the submit via something like this...

```
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
   $(location).attr('href','http://example.com/example');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
 alert('data has been saved successfully');
 window.location.href="http://google.com";
});
```